# How can I print to the console in c++?

Tags: c++

How can I print to the console in c++? I'm not sure how, and `print("")` doesn't work like in python. help please! I am not sure what to try now.

Comment: `I'm not sure how, and print("") doesn't work like in python.` Thats correct, C++ is not Python. A good C++ book should explain how to print to the console.

Comment: #include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; return 0; }

Comment: "I am not sure what to try now." - I would suggest [reading a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: As others mentioned, you probably want to read a good book. If nothing, at least a good tutorial on YouTube. This would probably be the first tutorial

Comment: Literally the first tutorial on any site would show you this. Also, simply Googling "c++ print console" would give you millions of results. There is less than no research effort here.

Answer (score 1):

If you include a library called iostream with #include  at the beginning of your code.

This will allow you use something like `cout << "Text Here";`
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Include `<iosstream>` and print using `cout << "Text Here";`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

... 


cout << "Text Here";
```